# How to access the whole public dataset hosted on a website?

Tags: search, dataset, kaggle

Say, on this [USGS website](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/search/), you could look up individual/group of earthquakes based on the filters they provide to you. I am wondering how can one access the entire dataset behind this search engine, so that one can then add their own filters to find specific data much more efficiently.

I think one way is to contact the website and they may have a way to share this with you, but I think inherently you should be able to extract this yourself without having to contact them, as I can totally imagine a way one can do this completely manually (but definitely will take a long time!).

I found this [Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/grigol1/earthquakes-2000-2023?resource=download) that essentially did what I am imagining, but I am just curious how they managed to pull this data, especially if they could do this without having to contact the website.

Comment: _"I think inherently you should be able to extract this yourself without having to contact them"_ - why do you think that? The USGS database is huge. Making the entire database freely downloadable could cost USGS a fortune in bandwidth charges

Comment: Just because it's theoretically (though perhaps not practically) possible to do this entirely manually. I just feel there should be a way to automate this.

Comment: also, the tool I have in mind obviously is a specialty tool that only a few people would ever use infrequently, and for most data queries of course what they already provide on their website is sufficient. I don't really see a bandwidth issue.

Comment: also if you look at the Kaggle dataset, it's almost everything on USGS already and it's only slightly above 100 MB. I imagine the full thing is very likely less than 200 MB.